# Open problems for shifted symplectic structures

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, derived-algebraic-geometry

I am now interested in shifted symplectic structures.

What are the open problems of shifted symplectic structures regarding the moduli space of sheaves ?

Especially now I am interested in moduli space of sheaves on K3 surface.

Any comment welcome! Thank you!